# Call Apache variable in laravel env

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So i want to call some apache variables into .env file in laravel 5.4 it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Apache variable in one of the config files (existing or a custom one) by using [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php). Just add similar line to one of config files in `/config` directory:

```
'variable' => getenv('APACHE_VARIABLE'),
```

Then, you'll be able to use this variable in any class and any view of your Laravel application with:

```
config('configFile.variable')
```